# Line 1034: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'char'

Tags: c++

I have tried to execute this code but it keeps throwing this error. could you help me fix it?

"Line 1034: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'char' (stl_vector.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:9"

```
vector<char> parenth;
    int top = -1;
    
    //pushing
    if(top == -1){
        top++;
        parenth[top]= x;
    }else{
        top++;
        parenth[top] = x;
        //popping
        switch (x){
            case ')' :
                if(parenth[top-1] == '('){
                    top -=2;      
                }
            case '}' :
                if(parenth[top-1] == '{'){
                    top -=2;      
                }
            case ']' :
                if(parenth[top-1] == '['){
                    top -=2;      
                }
        }
                    
    }
```

Comment: `vector<char> parenth;` is an empty vector. It has 0 elements. As you never do something that changes its size any access via `[]` is out of bounds

Comment: ot: code >> comments. The comment says "pushing" but thats misleading, as the code does not actually push. Better/correct code would not need the comment

Comment: Change this: `parenth[top]` to this: `parenth.at(top)`.   Then you will get a much more descriptive error message than the one you are receiving now.

Comment: *could you help me fix it?* -- As to this question, you first need to know what is wrong.  Then once you know that, it's your responsibility to attempt to make the corrections.

Answer (score 1):

The **problem** is that you've created an empty vector and then trying to access that empty vector's elements leading to **undefined behavior**.

To **solve** this you can make the vector to be of a particular size at the time of its creation and then use `std::vector::at` so that an exception is thrown if we accidentally go out of bounds of the vector and so there is no more UB.

```
//--------------------v--------->pass the size that you want your vector to have
vector<char> parenth( 5 ); 

//some code here 

//------vv----------------------->use std::vector::at so that if we mistakenly go out of bounds the exception is thrown and we don't get UB
parenth.at(top) = x;
```