# Correct way to pass std::vector from class to external function

Tags: c++, c++11, scope, std, stdvector

I am attempting to pass a std::vector of a custom class datatype to an function external to the main class. However, I am not sure of the best way to do this. Currently it produces segmentation faults.

Let me explain, I have tried to create a minimum reproducible example below:

I have a class in a header file `Poses.h`

```cpp
class Pose
{
  public:
  double x;

  Pose(double x_)
  {
    x = x_;
  }
};
```

In the main header, lets call it `foo.h`

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include "foofcn.h"

class foo{
  public:
  void begin()
  {
  std::vector<Pose> myPoses;
  myPoses[0] = Pose(1);
  myPoses[1] = Pose(2);
  foofcn(myPoses);
  }
};
```

Where `foofcn.h` is

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include "Pose.h"
#include <iostream> 

void foofcn(std::vector<Pose> myFooPoses)
{
  int xx;
  xx = myFooPoses[0].x;
  std::cout << xx << std::endl;
}
```

This currently produces an error: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Any help is appreciated

Comment: The problem is that `myPoses` is empty and you're writing `myPoses[0]` leading to undefined behavior. See dupe: [runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'char'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72445084/line-1034-char-9-runtime-error-reference-binding-to-null-pointer-of-type-cha)

Comment: Nothing to do with passing vectors, everything to do with how you are initialising the vector in the first place.

Comment: Sorry that was a syntax issue on my end. Yes you are correct.

Comment: Thank you all. Apologies for dupe. I thought the issue was due to the passing of the vector, not the initialisation.

Comment: Look at passing a vector by const reference, or just by reference if you will be manipulating it.

Comment: @huss987 You should *1)* **enable all warnings** and *2)* start using a debugger for your future programs. See [Why should I always enable compiler warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings) and [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Debug mode of the standard library can also be useful here (`-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` for libstdc++, etc), which says at runtime "Error: attempt to subscript container with out-of-bounds index 0, but container only holds 0 elements." (plus extra precisions).

Comment: And if your toolchain has sanitizers, you should at the very least use the address and undefined behaviour sanitizers. In GCC and GCC-like tools add `-fsanitize=address,undefined` to the command line.